# Hint text(Helper text at app startup) flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to implement helper text(hint text to user),When app opens on first time.I want to show hint text Like youtube and tiktok shows its hint text at startup(Swipe up to play,Swipe left to share)

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by hint text?  It would be better if you can show an image so that we can help

Comment: materialshowcaseview

Answer (score 2):

[showcaseview](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) - A Flutter package allows you to Showcase/Highlight your widgets step by step.

[image]